# Replaced Root Site but its Subsites Disappeared

Tags: sharepoint-online

I replaced the root site of our Teamsite with a new modern site.  However, the old root site had a bunch of subsited that have now disappeared along with it!  I see the old site as archived but do not know how to bring it back or restore the old sites.  I only need the latter.  Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Invoke-SPOSiteSwap to replace root site.

1.After replacing the root site, the url of the source site becomes the url of the original root site.

2.The original root site will have a new url, which is the Archive URL entered when running the power shell.

3.All subsites contained with the source and target sites will be swapped.

eg:

Invoke-SPOSiteSwap -SourceUrl https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/modernSite -TargetUrl https://contoso.sharepoint.com -ArchiveUrl https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Archive

The url of original root site changed from https://contoso.sharepoint.com to https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Archive

The url of subsite in the original root site changed from https://contoso.sharepoint.com/test to https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Archive/test

The url of source site (Now, it's being replaced into a root site) changed from https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/modernSite to https://wendytest123.sharepoint.com

The url of the subsite in the source site changed from https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/modernSite/test to https://wendytest123.sharepoint.com/test

Comment: Thanks Lisa.  So if one of my archives sites is:
https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/archive-2020-03-13T045118Z/Production

Then what do I do to change it to 
https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/Production
or
https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Production

Comment: I am not very understanding of your issue now, after you change the root site, Subsites of original root site will not disappear, just the url changed.

Comment: Hi Lisa. So i had some sites like xxxx.sharepoint.com/ and xxxx.sharepoint.com/HR. I replaced that first one with a new modern site Increating using the SP Admin site. That worked and archived the old site. However it took all the sites in that site collection and archived them as well. I want to move the archived sits back to the main site collection. Is that clearer?

Comment: You can use Invoke-SPOSiteSwap to replace the original  root site back: Invoke-SPOSiteSwap -SourceUrl https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Archive -TargetUrl https://contoso.sharepoint.com -ArchiveUrl https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Archive1

Comment: OK, so I finally was able to restore it with Invoke-SPOSiteSwap.  But still want to replace the main site with a new modern one without archiving all the other subsites.  How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The site you select as the new root site must be a communication site (SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0), a modern team site that isn't connected to an Office 365 group (STS#3), or a classic team site (STS#0).

Replacing the root site with another site replaces the entire site collection with the new site collection. If your current root site has subsites, they'll be archived.

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/modern-root-site#swap-your-root-site

Comment: Thanks Lisa.  Yes, the replacement went find.  But the old site had several subsites which now throw 404s.  In SP Admin I see the old site, now archived.  But I do not see the sites that were under it.  Its those, not the old root site, I need to restore.

Comment: I had sites like https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/HR.  But that site is no longer there.  It and several more now throw 404s.  Just becaue I replaced the root site.

Comment: You will have to restore the site collection, the subsites are a part of that. In SP Administration only site collections are listed.

Comment: Thanks Rune.  But how is that done.  It is not obvious from either classic of new SP Admin sites.  I do see the site collection in he Classic admin, and the missing sites are browaeable ther, but i dont know how to get them back to the new site collection